# libpng containing a security vulnerability Warning

Tags: android-security

I have question about a warning that I received yesterday in google play developer console, below I attached a image.

[image]

It's about libpng library security vulnerability. 
I think that I don't use this library in my project or if I use it I cannot find it.

In my project I use the following libraries:

- AdvancedLayers-1.0-20150422.082825-48;
- greendao-1.3.7; jts-1.13; jump-core-1.2;
- nutiteq-3d-sdk-2.4.2-22042015;
- shapefilereader-1.0;

Can somebody tell me how to fix this problem?
Thank you!

Comment: I also same problem.  I don't use this library in my project and cannot find it. Maybe it's a part of framework that i used (Android JNI)

Answer (score 0):

A simple fix is to extract the following zip file into your “cocos2dx\platform\third_party\android\prebuilt” folder:

Download the fix from here:
libpng_fix.zip for Cocos2d-x 2.x

And change “Android.mk” file under “cocos2dx” folder:

Change:
LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES := cocos_libpng_static

to
LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES := cocos_libzlib_static
LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES += cocos_libpng_static

Change:
$(call import-module,libpng)

to:
$(call import-module,libzlib)
$(call import-module,libpng)

courtesy: [Bengigi Apps and Games](http://www.bengigi.com/)